# Can I trust the stack traceback symbol names in a fatal exception that occurs early in the startup in my C++/STL/MFC application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am getting access violations in `mfc90d.dll` in `CObject:IsKindOf`, the deepest item on the call stack, which is actually apparently run long before `WinMainCRTStartup` is, and which probably is in my app because I wrote a standard container of some of my application's model objects;  `std::map<int, CDevice*>` somewhere, leading to the following templated container C++ type existing, and then showing up in my call stack:

```
myapp.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,CDevice   
         *,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,CDevice *> >,0> 
          >::_Copy(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,CDevice 
         *,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,CDevice *> >,0> > &                     
         _Right={...})  Line 1067 + 0x1d bytes  C++
```

I am not 100% sure that the `std::map<int, CDevice*>` is the reason, but it's the only templates reference involving "CDevice*" that I could find.

The whole call stack, given slightly simplified (ellipsis `...` indicates omission of some details of the function signature).

```
mfc90d.dll!CObject::IsKindOf(const CRuntimeClass * pClass=0x691a09ec)  
mfc90d.dll!CDocManager::OpenDocumentFile(const char * lpszFileName=0x007783e8)  
mfc90d.dll!CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile(const char * lpszFileName=0x007783e8)  
myapp.exe!CServerApp::InitInstance()  
mfc90d.dll!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00400000, HINSTANCE__ * ...            
    myapp.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 574 + 0x35 bytes    C
myapp.exe!WinMainCRTStartup()  Line 399 C
kernel32.dll!762033aa()     
ntdll.dll!77369ef2()    
ntdll.dll!77369ec5()    
myapp.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,CDevice ..........
```

Questions:

1. I'm a bit mystified about how something like `std::_Tree<...>::_Copy` can be executing so many layers of stuff FOUR entire call layers layers above `myapp.exe!WinMainCRTStartup`. Should I suspect the callstack above of being incorrect?
2. What's an std::_Tree<...> mess like the above there for and why is it invoking `CObject:IsKindOf`? My code uses the STL like this:  `std::map<int, CDevice*>`.
   My guess is that if I removed all references to `std::map<int, CDevice*>` then the 
   above `std::_Tree` internal implementation code would go away.
3. Running this far before `WinMainCRTStartup` suggests to me that this code is actually run when the `mfc90d.dll` loads. Is that probably so?  Is there anything I can do in VC++2008 debugger to get a clearer view of "when is this code running?"
4. It's unreasonable to ask for someone to guess for me how on earth crashes can occur
   this early in my application's lifetime. I am interested in how you debug such problems though, so if any of this rings a bell for you, I'd appreciate your thoughts and ideas, but it's too much to ask anybody to guess what's really going on.  Let's just say it's random heap corruption, somehow. But if you have tips on the order of "switch from using MFC in a dll to statically linking MFC", I'd like to hear those.

Comment: Why simplify the call stack?  I cannot trust it something simplified by someone who does not understand what is going in.  :). Do you have global or static map instances?  Do you have any global or static data with non trivial constructors at all?

Comment: By simplify I mean look where I put `....`. Only those places are simplified, and the full version of the AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE) line is hardly mysterious to ATL/MFC/C++ devs.  The full std::_Tree is printed out in a readable form at the top of the question. If you really want the full `AfxWinmain` line, I'll put that in too.

Comment: I don't know enough to answer the question "do you have global or static map instances?"  Could I look in the .map file and find those?  I am guessing you're on to something there. I'm a bit rusty in C++ and haven't dealt with STL much.  I suspect that the static map instances if any, are elements that are automatically added to my app by the `CDocManager` class in MFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything below ntdll.DLL is a red herring, in my experience.  Your std map did not call code in ntdll which called win main.  The debugger is interpreting nonsense and trying to makes sense of it, and some semi random binary data had an address that lined up with one of your functions.  Pretend it is not there.

Comment: So my map file may contain this symbol, and the stack unwind "randomly" selected this because of noise on the stack?

Comment: Yep.  Stack trace information "below" code you have no symbols for is unreliable.  It can even be deterministically so, because it is not random noise just not at all arranged the way your debugger expects.